# Customer Document Libary: How to organize a libary to store information effectively?

Tags: custom-list

I need to create a list to contain information about customers and a library to contain document relate to these customers.
A customer List Column:

- Customer Name
- Customer ID

A Document List: Can I create a folder for each Customer?

- Folder columns: Customer Name, Customer ID
- File in Folder Property: Customer Name, Customer ID, Product Buy, Sale Order Number... (The names of documents between clients may be the same)

Is such a list system effective?

Comment: Are you on a premises sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* go with two lists (Customer List and Sale Documents) and attach all the transaction metadata to each document. The downside to that approach is that you may have multiple documents with the same information.

I would recommend an approach with one additional list:

**Customer List**

- Customer Name
- Customer Phone
- Customer ID (unique)

**Sales Documents (one or more per transaction)**

- Document Name
- Order Number
- Customer ID

**Transaction List (one per transaction)**

- Order Number
- Product
- Cost, etc.
- Customer ID

I don't know what sort of transactional volume you're going to be working with here, but I would not go with a folder-based approach. Since the documents will have good, filterable metadata, consider segmenting them using views, instead.

You might also consider a single point of entry in the UI for end-users: e.g. an InfoPath (or PowerApp, if on SPO) form that accepts each sales transaction and any associated documents. For each new entry, a SharePoint workflow (or Flow, if on SPO) could tag and store the documents, log the transaction, and create a customer record - if one doesn't already exist. Could be pretty slick.

Good luck to you, and good idea to think things through before building. Your scenario is generally one that SharePoint can handle quite nicely when it's setup the right way.

Comment: Thanks, Jake. But I also need to store the Transaction Document beside the document provided by the client. If I have 10 document item per transaction and divide two-part belong 2 departments, can you recommend me a specific solution?

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to change the folder approach and go for a one customer is one Site Collection/Group/Teams.
The content is still using the same content types, now just managed from the content type hub or in your site design.
This approach will give you a max flexibility as you can manage permissions, sharing, external access out of the box

Comment: It's mean you use One Site Collection for a purchase order. Is it a bit too bulky? Specifically, how do you do it?

Comment: Compare it to any CRM or ERP system, they have a similar architecture. Each customer could be a site collection, and within that a library for RFPs, another for POs (most likely based on document sets). On top of that a search based dashboard pulling content from the site collections, such as contracts about to expire and so forth